# How to print session id in logs by post processor in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Can i print session id (which i extract by Regex in previous request response)
in logs by JSR223 postProcessor sampler(groovy)

Thnks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your variable can be access using [vars](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), for example if you save it as `sessionId`:

```
 log.info("Session id=" + vars.get("sessionId"));
```

> vars - (JMeterVariables) - gives read/write access to variables
>
> log - (Logger) - can be used to write to the log file

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that it is recommended to use JMeter's built-in test elements and void scripting where possible so I would rather suggest considering using [__log() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) in order to print the value like:

1. Double check that your variable is defined and has the value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination
2. Once you verify that the variable is there you can print it to the log using the following syntax:

   ```
   ${__log(${your_variable_reference_name)}
   ```

   [image]

---

If you still want to proceed with Groovy - the equivalent syntax would be:

```
log.info(vars.get('id'))
```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information if needed

Comment: Whats the sampler you have usd  in the red highlighted box in the above image?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it's for demonstration/illustration purposes, I believe it was either yet another [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or most probably a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide)